# Is there a way to enable pinch zoom on an image map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, imagemap

I'm having trouble in implement both pinch zoom by hammer.js and image map, after I put in the pinch zoom the image is able to zoom in and drag but unable to click on the area map which I have been written earlier. Any solution to this?

**HTML**

```
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="hammer.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="hammer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="hammer.fakemultitouch.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="hammer.showtouches.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div class="content">
        <div id="pinchzoom">
            <img src="images/map.jpg" width="529" height="300" id="rect" alt="Zoo" usemap="#zoomap">
            <map name="zoomap">
                <area shape="circle" coords="200,200,50" href="javascript:openPopup3" alt="NYTimes" >
            </map>
        </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var hammertime = Hammer(document.getElementById('pinchzoom'), {
    transform_always_block: true,
    transform_min_scale: 1,
    drag_block_horizontal: false,
    drag_block_vertical: false,
    drag_min_distance: 0
});

var rect = document.getElementById('rect');



var posX=0, posY=0,
    scale=1, last_scale,
    last_posX=0, last_posY=0,
    max_pos_x=0, max_pos_y=0;

hammertime.on('touch drag transform dragend', function(ev) {
    switch(ev.type) {
        case 'touch':
            last_scale = scale;
            break;
        case 'drag':
            if(scale != 1){
                posX = saved_posX + ev.gesture.deltaX;
                posY = saved_posY + ev.gesture.deltaY;
                if(posX > max_pos_x){
                    posX = max_pos_x;
                }
                if(posX < -max_pos_x){
                    posX = -max_pos_x;
                }
                if(posY > max_pos_y){
                    posY = max_pos_y;
                }
                if(posY < -max_pos_y){
                    posY = -max_pos_y;
                }
            }else{
                posX = 0;
                posY = 0;
                saved_posX = 0;
                saved_posY = 0;
            }
            break;

        case 'transform':
            scale = Math.max(1, Math.min(last_scale * ev.gesture.scale, 10));
            max_pos_x = Math.ceil((scale - 1) * rect.clientWidth / 2);
            max_pos_y = Math.ceil((scale - 1) * rect.clientHeight / 2);
            if(posX > max_pos_x){
                posX = max_pos_x;
            }
            if(posX < -max_pos_x){
                posX = -max_pos_x;
            }
           if(posY > max_pos_y){
                posY = max_pos_y;
            }
           if(posY < -max_pos_y){
                posY = -max_pos_y;
            }
            break;
        case 'dragend':
            last_posX = posX < max_pos_x ? posX: max_pos_x;
            last_posY = posY < max_pos_y ? posY: max_pos_y;
            break;
    }

    // transform!
   var transform =
        "translate3d(0, 0, 0) " +
        "scale3d(1, 1, 0) ";
    if(scale != 1){
       transform =
            "translate3d("+posX+"px,"+posY+"px, 0) " +
            "scale3d("+scale+","+scale+", 0) ";
    }

    rect.style.transform = transform;
    rect.style.oTransform = transform;
    rect.style.msTransform = transform;
    rect.style.mozTransform = transform;
    rect.style.webkitTransform = transform;

});
```

Comment: Properly indented the code and separated the HTML and javascript so the code can be Highlighted properly